# Assembling a party of adventurers

Tags: game-maker

Ok, so my little dungeon runner game has its functioning adventurer characters as objects, but unfortunately I'm having trouble figuring how to let the player assemble a party of four of them like I originally intended. I suspect I will need to have a room/menu before the "dungeon" room proper where the player selects which four adventurers will be assigned to an object array that will be used in the subsequent dungeon, but I'm having difficulty finding specifics on how to properly do that in Game Maker Studio 2. Does anyone else have any experience doing this or similar they'd like to share?

EDIT: Teammates don't need to have any AI beyond following behind the "leader"; in fact, the player only controls the head of the party, which they will be able to cycle out with another member in party order during the dungeon run with the press of a single key. I might have only the character the player is controlling take damage as well, but either way each party member has their own individual HP tracks that renders them unusable when it goes below '0'.

Comment: Is this more of a JRPG or more of an action adventure with AI-controlled teammates?

Comment: @Philipp Technically action, but the other party members technically don't need to do anything besides follow behind the leader (that the player controls) and keep track of their own HP and mana totals as well as what abilities are triggered when certain inputs are given while they're in the lead.

Comment: Honestly right now all I have that works is hard-coding for each character that pressing a certain button swaps them out for the next one in a specific order (fighter->alchemist->rogue->cleric->fighter); I've been trying to find tutorials on how to make a menu screen to fill an array with player-selected objects to use for the party but my google-fu has failed me in that regard.